# Como localizar um valor em um array com uma estrutura específica

Tags: php, array

Preciso localizar a posição de um array dentro de outro, na seguinte estrutura:

```
array{
  [0]=>{
    ["id"]=>"5744"
    ["fk"]=>"7"
    ["nome"]=>"Nivel 1"
    ["created"]=>"2014-04-30 16:54:14"
    ["modified"]=>NULL
    ["user_created"]=>NULL
    ["sadmin"]=>"N"
    ["color"]=>NULL
  }
  [1]=>{
    ["id"]=>"5745"
    ["fk"]=>"5744,7"
    ["nome"]=>"Nível 2"
    ["created"]=>"2014-04-30 16:56:21"
    ["modified"]=>NULL
    ["user_created"]=>NULL
    ["sadmin"]=>"N"
    ["color"]=>NULL
  }
  [2]=>{
    ["id"]=>"5746"
    ["fk"]=>"5745,5744,7"
    ["nome"]=>"Nível 3"
    ["created"]=>"2014-04-30 16:57:15"
    ["modified"]=>NULL
    ["user_created"]=>NULL
    ["sadmin"]=>"N"
    ["color"]=>NULL
  }
}
```

Como exemplo: eu possuo o valor `5746` e tenho que fazer a busca através dele, ou seja, preciso de tudo que se encontra na posição 2 do array.

**Estou editando para adicionar uma informação importante que acabei não mencionando:**

o array é extremamente grande, e precisarei realizar esta busca muitas vezes neste mesmo array, por isso preciso de um solução sem `foreach`, que faça uma busca direta sem que eu tenha que percorrer todo o array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muito me admira muitas respostas, inclusive respostas votadas, apontarem como solução um código engessado, que filtram a matriz a uma única ocorrência, manualmente codificada num mero condicional.

Bom... Minha sugestão é similar a dada pelo amigo @Cahe, porém ela muito mais enxuta e mata o problema com precisão de sniper e, de quebra, ainda se vale de recursos mais modernos da linguagem: Iterators.

Não foi uma solução criada por mim, daí a documentação em inglês, mas eu mantive os créditos do autor, inclusive o link de onde o *snippet* foi retirado. Mas infelizmente, ou o mesmo foi removido do manual, ou suprimido durante a repaginada do site.

```
/**
 * Searches value inside a multidimensional array, returning its index
 *
 * Original function by "giulio provasi" (link below)
 *
 * @param mixed|array $haystack
 *   The haystack to search
 *
 * @param mixed $needle
 *   The needle we are looking for
 *
 * @param mixed|optional $index
 *   Allow to define a specific index where the data will be searched
 *
 * @return integer|string
 *   If given needle can be found in given haystack, its index will
 *   be returned. Otherwise, -1 will
 *
 * @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#97645
*/
function search( $haystack, $needle, $index = NULL ) {

    if( is_null( $haystack ) ) {
        return -1;
    }

    $arrayIterator = new \RecursiveArrayIterator( $haystack );

    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator( $arrayIterator );

    while( $iterator -> valid() ) {

        if( ( ( isset( $index ) and ( $iterator -> key() == $index ) ) or
            ( ! isset( $index ) ) ) and ( $iterator -> current() == $needle ) ) {

            return $arrayIterator -> key();
        }

        $iterator -> next();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Para utilizar, obviamente basta invocar a função passando o array a ser buscado no primeiro argumento e aquilo que se busca no segundo.

```
var_dump( search( $valores, '5745,5744,7' ) ); // Saída int(2)
```

Opcionalmente temos o terceiro argumento que permite a você restringir a busca à um índice especifico da matriz.

No exemplo de uso imediatamente acima ficaria:

```
var_dump( search( $valores, '5745,5744,7', 'fk' ) );
```

Não chega a ser um ganho de performance pois toda a lógica reside num único IF, mas é uma alternativa que merece ser levada em consideração.

A função retorna um inteiro que deve ser usado para acessar os índices da matriz:

```
var_dump( $valores[ search( $valores, '5745,5744,7', 'fk' ) ] );
```

Atente apenas que esse exemplo didático leva em conta um valor real e existente. Numa aplicação real em que o valor que se busca pode não existir, deve ser feita uma verificação caso a função retorne **-1**, haja vista que, obviamente, **-1** não é um índice válido para uma matriz, mesmo que seja, indevidamente, válido para o PHP.

Comment: Perfeito cara, era exatamente o que precisava, sem um laço pra percorrer todo o array e extremamente rápido...

Comment: Ele faz um laço, mas por utilizar de Iterators, principalmente um recursivo, a tarefa é muito melhor desempenhada do que invocar a própria função de novo, de novo e de novo a cada novo array aninhado à estrutura.

Comment: Saquei. Valeu fera!

Answer (score 7):

Não sou experiente em `php` mas, acho que isso pode ajudar.

Assumindo que o array de entrada seja o que você passou nomeado como `$valores`:

```
$valores = array(
  0 => array(
    "id" =>"5744",
    "fk" =>"7",
    "nome" =>"Nivel 1",
    "created" =>"2014-04-30 16:54:14",
    "modified" =>NULL,
    "user_created" =>NULL,
    "sadmin" =>"N",
    "color" =>NULL),

  1 => array(
    "id"=>"5745",
    "fk"=>"5744,7",
    "nome"=>"Nível 2",
    "created"=>"2014-04-30 16:56:21",
    "modified"=>NULL,
    "user_created"=>NULL,
    "sadmin"=>"N",
    "color"=>NULL),

  2 => array(
    "id"=>"5746",
    "fk"=>"5745,5744,7",
    "nome"=>"Nível 3",
    "created"=>"2014-04-30 16:57:15",
    "modified"=>NULL,
    "user_created"=>NULL,
    "sadmin"=>"N",
    "color"=>NULL)
);
```

E para buscar o ID, você pode usar um simples `for`:

```
// Busca pelo elemento de ID 5746

foreach ($valores as &$valor) 
{
    if($valor["id"] == "5746")
    {
        // Array encontrado.
        print_r($valor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Se você precisar encontrar o valor `5746` independente da chave você pode fazer:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val){
  if (in_array("5746", $val)){
     $find = $val;
  }
}
print_r($find);
```

Ou se você precisa encontrar o valor `5746` para a chave `id`, você pode fazer;

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val){
  if ($val['id'] == 5746){
     $find = $val;
  }
}
print_r($find);
```

Uma opção também seria usar um `callback` da função [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($ar) { return ($ar['id'] == '5746'); });
```

Comment: Vou tentar utilizar com o `array_filter()` e dou um feedback na sequencia...

Comment: Utilizei o array_filter, não tinha me lembrado dessa função, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Mesmo que a pergunta esteja parcialmente resolvida, vou deixar um exemplo de uma implementação alternativa da função `array_search` onde você pode "filtrar" um membro de uma array por determinados valores:

```
function array_match($needle, $haystack, $strict = TRUE)
{
    foreach($haystack as $key => $member) {
        if(is_array($member) === FALSE)
            continue; // procuramos somente em arrays
        $tomatch = count($needle); // quantos valores precisam ser iguais
        $matches = 0;
        foreach($needle as $nkey => $nvalue) {
            if(isset($member[$nkey]) === FALSE)
                break; // a sub-array não possui o valor
            if($strict === TRUE) {
                if($member[$nkey] === $nvalue)
                    $matches++;
                else
                    break; // o valor é diferente do que queremos
            } else {
                if($member[$nkey] == $nvalue)
                    $matches++;
                else
                    break; // o valor é diferente do que queremos
            }
        }
        if($tomatch == $matches)
            return $key; // encontramos
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Exemplo:

```
$needle = array(
    "id"=>"5746",
    "nome"=>"Nível 3",
    "sadmin"=>"N"
);
echo array_match($needle, $data); // "2"
```

O código acima retorna o índice de `$data` que possua os mesmos elementos e valores de `$needle`, opcionalmente você pode dizer se a comparação dos valores deve ser estrita (`===`) ou não.

Answer (score 3):

A partir do PHP 5.5.0, a nova função array_column() poderá simplificar os scripts que comumente usamos.

```
print_r( array_search( '5746', array_column( $array, 'id' ) ) );
```

Consulte o manual: http://php.net/array_column

Answer (score 1):

```
    function busca($valores, $id){
        foreach($valores as $key => $value){
            if ($value['id'] == $id){
                return $value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    var_dump(busca($valores, "5746"));
```